# What is "Added Security" in the Microsoft Edge address bar?

Tags: security, ssl, https, microsoft-edge

I have started noticed "Added Security" in the Microsoft Edge address bar.

[image: "Added Security" shown in Microsoft Edge address bar]

It's giving me flashbacks to [EV SSL certificates](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-extended-validation-certificate). I've searched a bunch and can't find what this **exactly** means. Clicking on it does not explain. It does not appear for all https websites. So what makes this appear and what is "Added" that is not for other sites?

Comment: Care to give us an example of a website that does display it?

Comment: I see it for https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/?ql=4

Comment: Windows 10 or Windows 11? I can't reproduce on the current version of Microsoft Edge.  However, I have a environment, that might be causing it NOT to reproduce.  I just want to verify we are talking about Chromium Edge not Legacy Edge.

Comment: Could be related to what's reported in [this Neowin news article](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-edge-980110843-adds-new-browsing-mode-for-enhanced-security-and-lots-more/).

Comment: @Ramhound Chromium Edge, Windows 10.

Comment: Win10 and Chromium Edge here as well, just seeing the standard https padlock on that location. The shield shape reminds me of Windows Security though, could that be its browser protection plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is described in the article
[How to get more out of Edge (and bolster its security)](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3642833/how-to-get-more-out-of-edge-and-bolster-its-security.html)
together with the Microsoft documentation of
[EnhanceSecurityMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#enhancesecuritymode).

This refers to the security level as set in
*3-dot menu > Settings*. Enter `security` in the search box and you will
see this option:

[image]

You may enable or disable this entire option,
or choose "Balanced" which adds security protection for sites you
don’t visit often. The "Strict" option boosts security for *all*
sites, but site Exceptions can be added.

I haven't any detailed definition of what enhanced security actually does.
It's quite possible that Microsoft keeps to itself the option of modifying
this in coming versions of Edge.

Comment: I would agree, this has something to do with Enhanced Security Mode, which was introduced in Edge 98.

Comment: Detailed explanation in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-security-browse-safer